# Method setFrom is deprecated

Tags: magento2.4.4, methods, deprecated

Method setFrom is deprecated
Declared in Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
Is there any alternative?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the alternative is `setFromByScope`. In fact `setFrom` is now an alias of it.

For instance, the test file `vendor/magento/magento2-ee-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Rma/Controller/Returns/SubmitTest.php` makes use of the scope related method.

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With new implementation, magento 2.4 is recommended setFromByScope as an alternative.

**Change:**

- ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())

**To**

- ->setFromByScope($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Module\Test\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

/**
 * @var TransportBuilder
*/
private $transportBuilder;

class Main implements MailInterface
{
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
       ...
        try {
            $transportBuilder = $this->transportBuilder
               ...
                ->setFromByScope($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
               ...
            $transportBuilder->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```