# Method setFrom is deprecated in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

Method setFrom is deprecated. Is Magento 2.4 any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a new implementation, Magento 2.4 is a recommended setFromByScope alternative.

Change:

->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
To

->setFromByScope($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Module\Test\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

/**
 * @var TransportBuilder
*/
private $transportBuilder;

class Main implements MailInterface
{
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
       ...
        try {
            $transportBuilder = $this->transportBuilder
               ...
                ->setFromByScope($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
               ...
            $transportBuilder->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is setFromByScope. In fact setFrom

Original post:

[Method setFrom is deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359187/method-setfrom-is-deprecated/360773#360773)